# Detect iOS Game Center Login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

Is there a way to detect if the user gets this prompt?  I have seen this question a few times, but have never seen a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

[iOS Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) has a few examples on using the GameKit framework.

You should also look over the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Neither the samples or the programming guide really covered the scenario.  At least not that I could see.  It's possible it's just not supported and I will need to think of a workaround.  Thanks for the advice.